# How to set or get the recordtypeID of a related record?

Tags: apex

I need to get the recordTypeId of the related/lookup record from my trigger. See below code and I am getting error with Related__r.RecordTypeId

{Id relatedRecordTypeID = [select RecordTypeid from case where id =:newList.Related__r.RecordTypeId ];}

Comment: You are comparing Id with the recordtypeid in the where condition where it will fail for sure and also you need to query the newList.Related__r.RecordTypeId first or else you may get null value in it

Comment: you can try with this query select recordtypeid from account where id IN (select accountid from case)

Comment: you can try with this query: List<account> recordtypeids = [SELECT recordtypeid from account where id IN (select accountid from case where id IN:newList)];  Replace your account object with your object.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing SOQL on Case object where Id means CaseId but you are giving the newList.Related__r.RecordTypeId  in the where condition for comparison which will result in error.

Also newList.Related__r.RecordTypeId will result in Null because for any related objects in the trigger you need to query first the related data. The related data will result null if you are not querying them.

You may need to query the related object directly by adding the id as filter in where condition.